# before unload is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, frontend, onbeforeunload

here's my problem, I need to trigger a modal with a call to action when the user tries to get out from a page, I know if you use before unload event you must show an alert returning the text string from the function and that's fine.
BUT
no matter what I do, I always get the alert before my modal and only when the user has agreed to stay on the page from the built in browser alert.

I've seen in a website, some fronted genius managed to open an html modal right before the alert displays, so you can see the modal already there.

here's the code I'm using:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    _('#beforeunload').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    return 'You still have one item in your basket!';
 })
```

how can i trigger my foundation modal before the browser prompts the user whether to leave in the page or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Example

Comment: Tried:
`window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    _('#beforeunload').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    return 'You still have one item in your basket!';
 })`

Same result: the browser prompts to confirm to leave/refresh the page, after you accept to not leave the page, you get the foundation modal visible.
I need that to happen before of the standard alert.